# Normalizing columns in junction tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I have the following design.  `deleted_by` references the same `users` table for the three junction tables.  Should I further normalize this schema and put `deleted_by`, `date_deleted`, and `reason_of_delete` (and `added_by` and `date_added` which I haven't shown) in a separate table, and if so, how?

Side note.  I was struggling whether I should use the term `many-to-many` table, or `cross` table, or `join` table, or something else.  If I should be using a different term, please either advise so I may edit this post or edit it directly.  Thanks  EDIT.  Changed to "junction" table based on RBarryYoung's comment.

[image]

Comment: "*many-to-many table*" is not a common, nor IMHO a good term for these tables as it is confusing because it sounds like you are incorrectly calling a relation a table.  Terms I have heard for these types of tables are *Mapping Tables*, *Join Tables*, and *Relation Tables*.

Comment: Oh and *Junction Tables*

Comment: Having multiple tables with the same schema is usually a sign or poor design.

Comment: Just say either table, relation (as in Relational Model) or relationship (as in E-R Modeling), because a table/relation represents a relationship. ("Relationship" is also conventionally (mis)used to mean "foreign key".) But *describe* the relationship, ie what a user needs to know to put a row in or keep it out, ie what they know by seeing a row put in or kept out. "Has" says nothing. *Any* relationship can be called a "has (something to do with)" relationship. Communicate *which* relationship by giving a sentence in terms of column names that makes a statement when a row is plugged into it.

Comment: @RBarryYoung Surely an X table is the table/relation representing an X relationship/association? Especially if one's diagram is taken to describe tables/relations rather than E-R entity & relationship types or sets? (Maybe you use relation as a synonym for relationship/association?)

Comment: @philipxy Nope, surely not. The long-standing traditional convention is that a table is named after what it *contains*, and **not** after what it does nor how it is used.  This is why I prefer *Mapping Table*, because what it contains are *mappings*.  In any event "Many to Many table" does not appear to be used anywhere in the jargon or the culture, so I would suggest using one of the terms above that will be better understood by other practitioners.

Answer (score 1):

Many-to-many is fine as a description of this pattern. Without knowing all of the requirements of your system it's hard to make any definitive statement. The big question is, are those delete columns in reference to the document itself or in reference to that document's relationship with the other table (table2 for example). Assuming that they are in reference to the relationship itself, then putting them in the tables as you have them is perfectly fine. Although the many-to-many pattern often has just two IDs in a table, that is not at all a requirement.

If those delete columns are in reference to the document itself then they should be moved up to that table, otherwise you're duplicating data in multiple places and would have to worry about keeping it all in sync, which is a huge headache.

Comment: Apparently someone disagrees with my sentiment, but seems incapable of actually explaining why.

Comment: Hi Tom,  They relate to the relationship and not the document.  Just seems like I have a bunch of columns which are duplicated over many tables which normally seems wrong.  On this case, however, I can't see how I can move them.

Comment: If the columns hold legitimate data then it doesn't really matter that those column names are reused in a lot of different places. If I were to use "name" in my DB then it wouldn't necessarily be bad that it appeared in multiple tables.

Answer (score 0):

If you were going to have a deeper audit trail where your were tracking state changes along many columns, I'd say in that case you should have separate audit trail tables that are also persisted to when a transaction is processed.  Because you basically are only concerned with 3 state changes here for the entire table(s), (i.e. CrUD operations), I think just having additional audit trail columns would work here:  create_datetime, update_datetime and a status_flag that indicates state - or nature of the update (e.g. whether this was a delete operation, an update operation or other notable state describing the modification). You could also certainly have a 4th column, a description field, describing the nature of the state change as well.

Comment: Hi Dave,  Where would this audit trail columns reside?  Need they be in the junction tables?  They can't be in the `documents` entity table as the values are different based on which table is joined to it.

Comment: Based on your model, I think they'd then would have to be in the junction tables.  FWIW, while I generally recommend against it, sometimes having dupe columns while violating normal form is just easier to contend with.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use a supertable?  I would appreciate any comments.

[image]